# What did Victor do to Reed Richards during the final confrontation?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-four-2015

During the final fight between 2015's [*Fantastic Four*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1502712/) and Victor Von Doom on Planet Zero Victor achieves to impede all of the Four's attacks. His primary way of doing so seems to be to suffocate them with the rock material of Planet Zero itself, which he can control with his powers. This is how he buries Ben, extinguishes Johnny's fire and holds back Sue in her "forcefield bubble", if I remember correctly.

However, with Reed he merely seems to somehow paralyze him by pressing him to the ground or making his limbs immovable. It nearly seemed as if he made Reed lose control of his very own stretching power. **What did Victor actually do to Reed there?** Can he even control Reed's power somehow or his very body functions (we certainly saw him somehow "overheat" people earlier)? Or did he just press him to the ground by some external force inherent to Planet Zero or his energy controlling abilities?

Answer (score 2):

If my interpretation is correct, then what's happening in this scene requires you to have been paying *really* good attention to the earlier scenes, soon after the four got their powers.

Once of the lines of dialogue tells us that the Army invented the suits the team uses because, without the suits, they cannot control their own powers. In other words, Johnny can't turn off his flames, and Sue randomly fluctuates in and out of the visible spectrum.

It's not specifically mentioned, but presumably, the same is true of Reed. As far as I can tell, Reed also builds himself a similar type of suit and is wearing it the next time we see him.

What I believe you're supposed to notice in that scene is that Doom is somehow causing the joints on the suit to fail, which causes Reed to lose control over his stretching ability. Without the support of the suit, his limbs go limp and stretched-out, and he can't make them move.

Once Doom was distracted, Reed was able to regain control over his own powers and use them to help win the final battle.

Comment: That's an interesting angle I hadn't really considered. However, Reed certainly could control it to some degree even without his suit, seeing how he escaped the facility (and also when he bought those machine parts in Mexico). But I might buy that it was more difficult and stressful without the suit.

Comment: Again, none of that was actually *said* about Reed; it was only stated explicitly about Johnny and Sue. I just extrapolated.